# Multiple Left Joins have affected my SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am currently trying to create a report for the amount of time in total some individuals on my PHPBB3 forum have booked in, for the last week. Initially, I had the following query that worked as expected:

```sql
SELECT forum_users.username, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, schedule_slots.time_starting, schedule_slots.time_finishing)) AS seconds 
FROM forum_users 
LEFT JOIN schedule_slots 
    ON forum_users.user_id = schedule_slots.user_id 
    AND schedule_slots.time_starting >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
    AND schedule_slots.is_del = 0 
    AND schedule_slots.channel = 0
WHERE (forum_users.group_id = 8 OR forum_users.group_id = 5 OR forum_users.group_id = 14) 
GROUP BY forum_users.username 
ORDER BY upper(forum_users.username)
```

However, when I go to join another table, the timestamp difference ends up being incorrectly calculated (it's higher), here's my newer non working statement:

```sql
SELECT forum_users.username, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, schedule_slots.time_starting, schedule_slots.time_finishing)) AS seconds, group_concat(DISTINCT forum_user_group.group_id) AS user_groups 
FROM forum_users 
LEFT JOIN schedule_slots 
    ON forum_users.user_id = schedule_slots.user_id 
    AND schedule_slots.time_starting >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
    AND schedule_slots.is_del = 0 
    AND schedule_slots.channel = 0 
LEFT JOIN forum_user_group 
    ON forum_user_group.user_id = forum_users.user_id 
WHERE (forum_users.group_id = 8 OR forum_users.group_id = 5 OR forum_users.group_id = 14 OR forum_users.group_id = 12) 
GROUP BY forum_users.username 
ORDER BY upper(forum_users.username)
```

I'm drawing a blank on this one, and your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp difference is calculated right, but you multiply it by number of groups the user is in.

I would try:

```
SELECT forum_users.username, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, schedule_slots.time_starting, schedule_slots.time_finishing)) AS seconds, 
(select group_concat(DISTINCT group_id) from forum_user_group WHERE forum_user_group.user_id = forum_users.user_id) AS user_groups 
FROM forum_users 
LEFT JOIN schedule_slots 
ON forum_users.user_id = schedule_slots.user_id 
AND schedule_slots.time_starting >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
AND schedule_slots.is_del = 0 
AND schedule_slots.channel = 0 
WHERE (forum_users.group_id = 8 OR forum_users.group_id = 5 OR forum_users.group_id = 14 OR forum_users.group_id = 12) 
GROUP BY forum_users.username, user_groups 
ORDER BY upper(forum_users.username)
```